# Automate Generation of provision profile for given UDIDs

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to automatically generate the mobile provision profile with given new UDIDs with out the manual process of adding it in provision portal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In Xcode’s organizer which is accessed with Command-Shift-2: go to the devices tab, then in the Library list on the left click Provisioning Profiles. Then click refresh in the lower right corner.